# Extracting numbers from the parent attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, match, attr

By clicking on the "mylink" I want the link to be replaced by the number "123", which is extracted from parent tag.
I think I'm not doing the ".match(...." right.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".link").click(function(){
    var comid = $(this).parents("div.comment").attr("class").match(/comment-([0-9]+)/)[1];
    $(".link").replaceWith(comid);
  });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="comment comment-123 ct">
  <div class="link">mylink</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whenever I click on the link, it does nothing, as if there's an error

Comment: If I enter it without the ".match(/comment-([0-9]+)/)[1]" it replaces the link with the whole attr "comment comment-123 ct".
But i only want the numbers 123, not the whole attr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one matching so you need to use the 0th match (zero-based array).  Also, it will return the entire match, so if you want just the number you'll need to remove the `comment-` text from it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".link").click(function(){
    var comid = $(this).parents("div.comment")
                       .attr("class")
                       .match(/comment-[0-9]+/)[0]
                       .replace('comment-','');
    $(".link").replaceWith(comid);
  });
});
```

If there's a possibility that no match will occur, then you'd want to assign the matches to a variable and only do the replacement(s) if a match occurs (the variable is non-null).

Comment: Yes, this did it, I was just working in drupal, so had to rewrite the parentheses. .replace('comment-',''); should be .replace("comment-",""); Thanks